# How to include opencv and opencv_contrib modules in android studio 2.2 on ubuntu?

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, ubuntu, android-ndk

I've been trying to install the OpenCV and additional modules in opencv_contrib but I keep getting errors when trying to configure it. I have imported OpenCV so far but don't know how to import the additional opencv_contrib module as it is in C++. I know it is going to use NDK for c++ modules but I don't know the process to import them. I am using android-studio-2.2.3 on ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Have you imported OpenCV using File -> New -> Import Module? Also have you configured dependencies in Project Structure?

Comment: yes, I have imported opencv using using File -> New -> Import Module, but now I want to import the contrib modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the CMAKE pattern defined in the official github repository of OpenCV_contrib. Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md

Comment: after building it with opencv_contrib module, how to import it in android studio project??

Comment: The **How to Build OpenCV with extra modules** states that: "As the result, OpenCV will be built in the <opencv_build_directory> with all modules from opencv_contrib repository."

Do you have <OpenCV_build_directory> as output? If yes, you can directly import it as a module.